# add text to an existing cell in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, text, phpmyadmin, append

I want to add text to the the end of a cell in phpmyadmin, where it just adds the text to the end whatever in that cell, and keeps whatever there as is.

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
update items set description = contact(description, " - text to add") where parent_id ='2907'
```

So the cell should be instead of

```
something here
```

to be:

```
something here - text to add
```

Comment: there seems no problem in your query it should work, is there any error displayed??

Comment: ya, it brings: #1305 - FUNCTION DBname.contact does not exist

Comment: it is concat not contact in your querry,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your SQL statement. The function is called `CONCAT`, not <strike>contact</strike>.

Try this statement. If it doesn't work, please add the error message to your question.

```
update items
  set description = concat(description, " - text to add")
  where parent_id ='2907'
```